# when install fcgiwrap encounter make problem

Tags: ubuntu, makefile

via [this article](http://nginx.localdomain.pl/wiki/FcgiWrap) , i download fcgiwrap and extract it and cd in. but when i run make, error reported

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

ll .

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root  4096 2011-08-01 17:15 ./
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root  4096 2011-08-01 16:51 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  1251 2010-09-14 22:32 configure.ac
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  3220 2010-09-14 22:32 fcgiwrap.8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 16757 2010-09-14 22:32 fcgiwrap.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root    82 2010-09-14 22:32 .gitignore
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root   577 2010-09-14 22:32 Makefile.in
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  1624 2010-09-14 22:32 README.rst
```

there is a Makefile.in in current dir. why does `make` can't see it?

env: ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`make` looks for a `Makefile`. There isn't one: `Makefile.in` is not the same thing as `Makefile`. You need to run `aclocal`, `autoheader` and [`autoconf`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoconf) to generate `configure` from `configure.ac`; or, as the build instructions in the `README.rst` file tell you (you should read these files, you know), run `autoreconf -i`. Then you'll be able to run `./configure` to generate a `Makefile` and then `make` to build the program.